# How to display has_many in rails controller and template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

```
class Reflection < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :comments
end


class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :reflection
end
```

I have an application where a reflection has any comments.

In the index view for reflections, I would like to show a count of the number of comments each reflection has and also display the comments for each reflection, but I'm not able to figure out how to do this.

I am trying to understand what code to include in Reflection index controller as well as in the template (index.html.erb for Reflection). Any advice?

I am able to Display the comments for an individual reflection using the code below in the Reflections controller, but perhaps there's a better way to do this in rails.

```
  def show
    @comments = Comment.where(reflection_id: @reflection.id)
  end
```

```
I tried 

  <tbody>
    <% @reflections.each do |reflection| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= reflection.id %></td>
        <td><%= reflection.reflection %></td>
        <td><%= reflection.user_id %></td>
        <td>
//LOOPING THROUGH COMMENTS IN EACH REFLECTION
        <td><%= reflection.comments.each do |comment| %>
              <%= comment.comment %>, 
            <% end %>
        </td>
//END LOOPING THROUGH COMMENTS IN EACH REFLECTION
        </td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', reflection %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_reflection_path(reflection) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', reflection, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>


The above yields the comment but also the objects afterwards:

    fdsafdsa, fdsacdxzdv, [#<Comment id: 8, comment: "fdsafdsa", created_at: "2019-08-27 04:13:34", updated_at: "2019-08-27 04:13:34", reflection_id: 1, user_id: 1>, #<Comment id: 9, comment: "fdsacdxzdv", created_at: "2019-08-27 04:32:36", updated_at: "2019-08-27 04:32:36", reflection_id: 1, user_id: 1>]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller to fetch the comments, you could use

`@comments = @reflection.comments`
and then in view file to display the comments, you could loop through @comments.

To display the count of the number of comments in the view file you could use `@comments.size`

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

To remove the comment object from being displayed, try the below.
(I have removed the `=` before looping)

```
 <td><%reflection.comments.each do |comment| %>
              <%= comment.comment %>, 
            <% end %>
 </td>
```

For more info on rendering read ruby docs 
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html

Comment: This helps in the show controller for reflections, but in the reflections index controller, how would I show all comments for each reflection?

Comment: you can loop through refections and do reflection.comments to get the comments of each of the reflection

Comment: I included above how I'm looping through comments for each reflection in the reflection index view. i get the comments, but I also get the comments objects afterwards too. any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Have added the details in the answer, please check

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this too:

Display all comments for all reflections:

1. in the `reflections_controller`:

```
def index
  @reflections = Reflection.all
end
```

2. In the `index.html.erb`

```
<tbody>
  <% @reflections.each do |reflection| %>
    <tr>
     ...
      <td>
        <p> Comments(<%= reflection.comments.count %>) </p>
        <% reflection.comments.each do |comment| %>
          <%= comment.comment %>
        <% end %>
      </td>
        ...
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

Display all comments for a particular reflection:

1. in the reflections_controller:

```
def show
  @reflection = Reflection.find(params[:id])
end
```

2. in the show.html.erb:

```
...
<p>
  <strong>Comments(<%= @reflection.comments.count %>)</strong>
  <% @reflection.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= comment.comment %>
  <% end %>
</p>
...
```